# buttons that adds a number to a list and prints it out

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I'm trying to make a program that takes in a number and adds it to a list and then prints out the list with buttons but every time I run the program the output is wrong for example when I would type in 3 it would output "IDs" = [333] can anyone help me, please.

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(); //  store integers
        result.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    int temp = Integer.parseInt(input.getText()); // get the input
                    list.add(temp); // add it to the list
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The ID has been added");
                } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The number you entered is not a valid Integer", "Invalid Input",
                            JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE); // message to show if the input is invalid
                }
            }
        });
        show.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){ // print out the list
                        System.out.println("IDs : "+list.toString());
                    }
```

Comment: You say you are typing in 3.  Where do you type it? in some text area?  It would help if you showed more of your code.

Comment: You must be typing `333` in the textfield.

Comment: No I dont I only type in 3

Comment: What is result? What is actionPerformed listening for? Can we see more of the code, as right now there is no way to tell why it would be printing 333 if you're typing 3.